# ASP CKEditorControl's content length on client-side

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor in my ASP.NET webforms application. I'm using CKEditor control to put it to my page:

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditorControl" runat="server" />
```

But I'd like to get the editor's content length on client-side. I'm trying to do it this way:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['<%= CKEditorControl.ClientID %>'].getData().length;
```

Though it's not working because: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getData' of undefined"

So my question is. What am I doing wrong? And is it possible to get the CKEditor's length on client-side when using CKEditorControl?

Comment: Can you verify that the ClientID is outputting the correct ID?

Comment: Yes, it returns the correct ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code works:

```
$('#cke_<%= CKEditorControl.ClientID %> iframe').contents().find('body').html()
```

I'm not sure now but I guess all my problems were because I was trying to get the data before the editor was loaded.