# How to cause CKEditor textarea to refresh / update with client side changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, ckeditor

**SCRIPT**

```js
$('.DDL').change(function update() {
    $.get('../Folder' + $(this).val() + '.html', function(result) {  
        $('.CKE').val(result);
    });
});
```

**TEXTAREA**

```html
<asp:CKEditorControl ID="txtMailBody" CssClass="CKE" RunAt="Server" BasePath="~/Editor"/>
```

I have some jscript that populates my textareas with relevant content based on their selection.

The javascript works perfectly to populate any textarea.

It does not work when my textarea is my ckeditor.

Inspecting the page reveals that the content is being added but the ckeditor does not display it. Refreshing the page also causes the content to appear.

**QUESTION**

How can I cause a CKEditor textarea to refresh / update to show client side code that has been added on the fly from a dropdownlist?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use

```js
CKEDITOR.instances['txtMailBody'].setData(result);
```

instead of

```
$('.CKE').val(result);
```

..When you update the CKEditored' textarea.

---

### Try this little demo :

select box with text snippets to be inserted :

```
<select id="test">
<option>some text to be inserted</option>
<option>some other text</option>
<option>even more text</option>
</select>
```

A textarea that becomes a CKEditor instance

```
<textarea id="txtMailBody"></textarea>
```

script

```
//create the CKEditor instance
CKEDITOR.replace("txtMailBody"); 

$("#test").change(function() {
    var result = $("#test option:selected").text();
    //HERE
    CKEDITOR.instances['txtMailBody'].setData(result);
    //instead of $(textarea).val(result);
});
```

It is of course *only* when the target is a CKEditor you should use `CKEDITOR.instances['txtMailBody'].setData(result);`, otherwise - if it is a textarea, use the code you already have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. Is that the exact syntax because it doesn't even populate the textarea with that code replacement. What is the CKEDITOR part of your query referencing?

Comment: I just get CKEDITOR.instances.txtMailBody is undefined

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by your first comment :( You should use `CKEDITOR.instances[textarea-id].setData(result)` only when it is a textarea - instead of `$(textarea-id).val(result)`

Comment: I see the issue now is that CKEDITOR.instances only targets textareas.
I cannot use a text area I need to use <asp:CKEditorControl ID="txtMailBody" CssClass="CKE" RunAt="Server" BasePath="~/Editor"/> as my textarea because I have code behind.

Comment: Hey @DreamTek, I am not familiar with ASP.NET at all, but see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607713/asp-ckeditorcontrols-content-length-on-client-side) - appearently a different approach is needed when it is ASP and the CKEditor is generated serverside - perhaps `$('#cke_<%= CKEditorControl.ClientID %> iframe').setData(result)` do the trick? Cannot test it, dont have ASP.

Comment: Really appreciate your help David but it appears I am back to square one. $('.CKE').val(result);